# How to write docker-compose file for bbb (big blue button)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I find a Big Blue Button Dockerfile on [ bigbluebutton /docker ][1]  [1]: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/docker 
And second week I tryed to write docker-compose.yml file.
How to write docker-compose.yml file. I tried but not success.

This is Dockerfile [ bigbluebutton /docker ][1]  [1]: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/docker

```
    FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER ffdixon@bigbluebutton.org

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
# RUN echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.0.130:3142";'  > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget

RUN echo "deb http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/xenial-200 bigbluebutton-xenial main " | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bigbluebutton.list
RUN wget http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/repo/bigbluebutton.asc -O- | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade

# -- Setup tomcat7 to run under docker
RUN apt-get install -y \
  haveged    \
  net-tools  \
  supervisor \
  sudo       \
  tomcat7

RUN sed -i 's|securerandom.source=file:/dev/random|securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom|g'  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security
ADD mod/tomcat7 /etc/init.d/tomcat7
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/tomcat7

RUN apt-get install -y language-pack-en
RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# -- Install BigBlueButton
RUN echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y bigbluebutton
RUN apt-get install -y bbb-demo

# -- Install mongodb (for HTML5 client)
RUN sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org curl

# -- Install nodejs (for HTML5 client)
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
RUN echo 'deb-src http://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs

# -- Install HTML5 client
RUN apt-get install -y bbb-html5

# -- Install supervisor to run all the BigBlueButton processes (replaces systemd)
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# -- Modify FreeSWITCH event_socket.conf.xml to listen to IPV4
ADD mod/event_socket.conf.xml /opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs


# -- Finish startup
ADD setup.sh /root/setup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/setup.sh"]
CMD []
```

So this is my docker-compose file. But that file not worked. I lack knowledge  and qualification.

```
version: '3'
services:
  bigbluebutton:
    build: .
    image: bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton
    ports:
       - "80:80"
    expose:
    - "1935/tcp"
    - "5066/tcp"
    - "2202"
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Can you include the actual command you're running and the exact text of the error message you're getting?

Comment: They say to not use the docker image they provide, since its apparently not production ready. See also my remark to make it an official docker image instead: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/8861#issuecomment-620212573

Comment: To give you some more details, BBB v2.3 will support Ubuntu 18.04. It makes sense to roll-out a new docker image using Ubuntu 18.04 (I know not 20.04) together with BBB 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just you need lines below in Docckerfiles becuse bbb need configure and this code passing this step;

```
 `-RUN apt-get install -y bigbluebutton(remove)
 +RUN apt-get install -y bigbluebutton || :
 +RUN gem install bundler -v 1.16.1
 +RUN apt-get install -y bigbluebutton
  RUN apt-get install -y bbb-demo`
```

this is not bug just compile error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not indent correctly `expose` subsection. I would write:

```
version: '3'
services:
  bigbluebutton:
    build: .
    image: bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton
    ports:
       - "80:80"
    expose:
       - "1935/tcp"
       - "5066/tcp"
       - "2202"
```

If you use bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton image from DockerHub, you don't need neither `build` section nor `Dockerfile` itself.

Comment: Please support/help creating a new docker image for BBB v2.3 which supports Ubuntu 18.04. The current BBB docker image is out-dated.

Comment: @danger89 By any chance were you able to make the docker image? I'm in the same boat and would love to discuss

Comment: I didn't try to build the image, I just solved the docker-compose problem as expected in the initial request. It seems that the Dockerfile fails itself, without docker-compose. I don't know anything about bigbluebutton. Sorry.

Comment: Well there is: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/docker for now